# How to join every sublist to a single string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

How to join every sublist to a single string in Python?

Here is the list :

```
L=[['1', '1', '0', '0', '0'],['1', '1', '1', '1', '0'],['0', '0', '1', '1', '0']]
```

My desired list would be :

```
 D=['11000','11110','00110']
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: There are two steps to the problem, and each is a common duplicate. `''.join` can join a list of strings; apply that to each list in the list of lists.

Answer (score 5):

```
L = [['1', '1', '0', '0', '0'],['1', '1', '1', '1', '0'],['0', '0', '1', '1', '0']]
D = [''.join(sub_list) for sub_list in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a list comprehension:

```
L = [
    ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0']
    ]

D = [''.join(l) for l in L]
```

or the map function:

```
D = map(''.join, L) # returns a generator in python3, cast it to list to get one
```

Note that the most pythonic way of doing this is the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

### flat list can be made through `reduce` easily.

All you need to use *initializer* - third argument in the `reduce` function.

```py
reduce(
   lambda result, _list: result.append(''.join(_list)) or result, 
   L, 
   [])
```

#### or map and reduce in combination,

```py
import operator
map(lambda l: reduce(operator.iconcat, l), L)
```

Above code works for both python2 and python3, but you need to import reduce module as `from functools import reduce`. Refer below link for details.

- [for python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
- [for python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)